# Bad request when accessing asmx web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, http-status-code-400

I've been trying to create an ASMX web service and access it from a different computer (the server is running on localhost). I built the ASP Web application & ASMX web service, and added a simple HelloWorld function. In the IIS applicationhost config file I added a binding to my project with my IP (So I had one with localhost and one with the IP). Problem is, when I try to call the function from a different device (using the IP instead of localhost) I get a 400-Bad request error.

Update: Firewall and anti virus are both turned off.

My web service's config file:

[image: config file]
Bad request (also occurs when I call 192.168.1.10:8080/WS.asmx/HelloWorld) :

[image]

Comment: This sounds really basic but having been caught out numerous times myself... have you checked it's not your firewall? (Don't forget the Windows one). Failing that, what do the IIS logs say?

Comment: How do I check the IIS logs? Firewall is turned off.

Comment: I can't remember the path off the top of my head, they're in appdata somewhere? I'm not trying to be a jerk but just type "where are IIS logs" into your preferred search engine...

Comment: I checked the IIS logs - I can't find anything problematic, it doesn't give anything about an error or a bad request...

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I find it easier to stop my website, delete or move the existing logs, then start the site. Makes it easier to find the right log. The 400 error will definitely be logged as it's IIS that responds with that code.

Comment: Okay, I have found that it generates two log files: in one I see a GET to the web service (i.e. http://localhost:8081/WS.asmx) and the second one is a GET to an icon (? no idea. http://localhost:8081/favicon.ico) and it gets a 404 not found error. In another run, I got more logs (some of them referring to a call to localhost:helloWorld), but they all had a 200 response code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, no idea what was the thing that helped. I did three things:

```
1)Uninstalled Avast anti-virus (tried to turn its firewall off but wasn't sure if it was really off).
2) Ran Visual Studio AS ADMINISTRATOR (which is the solution in my opinion).
3) typed this in cmd: netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:8081/ user=Everyone .
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Always review your folder permission in the webservice folders. I ran into a bad request because my log files from the WS not IIS was written in app_data folder and on the new server, infrasctructure depto, didn't allowed IIS_USRS to write on that folder.

We didn't know why returned bad request, but solved.